# mongodb distinct the key of a map in an array which is a property of a document

Tags: mongodb, distinct

I use mongodb,one document format is like this:

```
{
    sid:2,
    attr:[
        {
            key:"name",
            value:"bike"
        },{
            key:"weight",
            value:"100"
        }
    ]
}
```

there is a property "attr" which is like a map with uncertain number of keys.
the whole collection look like this:

```
[{
    sid:1,
    attr:[
        {
            key:"name",
            value:"bike"
        }
    ]
},{
    sid:2,
    attr:[
        {
            key:"name",
            value:"bike"
        },{
            key:"weight",
            value:"100"
        }
    ]
},{
    sid:3,
    attr:[
        {
            key:"color",
            value:"red"
        },{
            key:"weight",
            value:"100"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Now, what I want to know is how many distinct keys there are,and what are them.
In this example,the distinct keys I expected should be:

```
["name","weight","color"]
```

but what about more document inserted into the collection?The data in this collection is not fixed

Comment: what should be the expected output?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet:     ["name","weight","color"]

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet   thanks a lot.It works.I will learn the api and verify if it is accurate later

Comment: Try `db.colname.distinct("attr.key")`

Comment: I tried,get a 57 result in my real table.the number is more,I need to check @Veeram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `attr` array then you can use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation to distinct the fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$attr" },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$attr.key" } }
])
```